# Casbah: No implicit view available error

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, casbah, salat

In a Play app, using Salat and Casbah, I am trying to de-serialize a `DBObject` into an object of type `Task`, but I am getting this error when calling `.asObject`:

> No implicit view available from com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBObject =>
>   com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.MongoDBObject. Error occurred in an
>   application involving default arguments.

The object is serialized correctly with `.asDBObject`, and written to the database as expected.

What is causing this behaviour, and what can be done to solve it? Here's the model involved:

```
package models

import db.{MongoFactory, MongoConnection}

import com.novus.salat._
import com.novus.salat.global._
import com.novus.salat.annotations._
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.Imports._
import play.api.Play


case class Task(label: String, _id: ObjectId=new ObjectId)

object Task {

  implicit val ctx = new Context {
    val name = "Custom_Classloader"
  }

  ctx.registerClassLoader(Play.classloader(Play.current))

  val taskCollection = MongoFactory.database("tasks")

  def create(label: String): Task = {
    val task = new Task(label)
    val dbObject = grater[Task].asDBObject(task)
    taskCollection.save(dbObject)
    grater[Task].asObject(dbObject)
  }

  def all(): List[Task] = {
    val results = taskCollection.find()
    val tasks = for (item <- results) yield grater[Task].asObject(item)
    tasks.toList
  }
}
```

**Versions**

```
casbah: "2.8.1"
scala: "2.11.6"
salat: "1.9.9"
```

Comment: Typo or err: double import of `com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._` dep.

Comment: Yes,  that is a typo :) But the error is not caused by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions on creating a custom context:

> - First, define a custom context as 
>     `implicit val ctx = new Context { /* custom behaviour */ }`
>     in a package object
> - Stop importing `com.novus.salat.global._`
> - Import your own custom context everywhere instead.

Source: https://github.com/novus/salat/wiki/CustomContext

Comment: Yep, that was it! I had to stop importing the global context and tweak the custom one a little bit. Thanks for the help!